# Ajax call in Django without a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

New to Ajax so I'm trying to get my head wrapped around things. I'm trying to make an Ajax call by wiring my Javascript event handler to the onclick for a span element. There's no form element in my template. Is it possible to make an Ajax call without a form element in Django? From what I understand it is, but I can't seem to get it to work.  When I take a look at the request in my view, there is no HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH header so the request.is_ajax() call always returns false.

Here's the relevant portion of my template:

```
<td><span class="header" onclick="sort_user_table('username')"><a href="">Username</a></span></td>
```

Here's my Javascript function:

```
function sort_user_table(col_name) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/listusers/",
    data: {sort_order: col_name},
    headers: {'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH': 'XMLHttpRequest'},
    type: "GET",
    dataType : "json",
    success: function(json) {
      alert('json = ' + json);
    },
  });
}
```

And here's my view:

```
def list_users_page(request):
  if request.is_ajax():
    sort_order = request.GET['sort_order']
    users = User.objects.all().order_by(sort_order)
    data = serializers.serialize('json', users)
    json_users = json.dumps(data)
    return HttpResponse(json_users, mimetype='application/json')
  else:
    users = User.objects.all().order_by('last_name')
    variables = RequestContext(request, {
      'users': users,
    })
    return render_to_response('users_page.html', variables)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I figured out what was happening. I made a mistake in posting my template code so it wasn't complete (I was trying to be brief, but ended up leaving out an important piece of info).  Here's what the real piece of code looks like:

```
<td><span class="header" onclick="sort_user_table('username')"><a href="">Username</a></span></td>
```

The `href` is what was causing the problem. Since it's actually a link, a request to a new resource was being made when I clicked on the Username `span` element. So although the javascript code was executing, it wasn't actually an Ajax request, it was a simple HTTP request.  If I simply remove the `href` from the `span` element, everything works as expected. The `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header is sent and my Django view responds true to `request.is_ajax()`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you may need to change:

1. It looks like you're using jQuery to make your AJAX call.  If that is the case, then you don't need to manually add any headers to make the server think it's an AJAX call as jQuery will do that automatically.
2. In the `request.is_ajax` block of your view you are calling `Users.objects.all()` (note the trailing `s` on `Users`) but `User.objects.all()` in your `else` block, so it's possible the problem you're getting is because of an invalid call to `Users`.

I would also recommend using the request inspection tools available in your browser to inspect the request headers, which will show you if everything is formed correctly.

You should also add an `error` callback in addition to `success` in your AJAX request options so that you can get more information back about what's failing if the request fails.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions.  The `Users` in the `request.is_ajax` block was a typo, my code was indeed `User.objects.all`. I left out the error callback for brevity. When I inserted that and checked the error it was simply the message "error", not very helpful. I did as you suggested and checked the request headers and the HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH header is not present in the request.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue with `href`'s in the elements. Removed them and it all works now.

Just a heads up: to check if request is ajax in Django use:

```py
if request.headers.get('x-requested-with') == 'XMLHttpRequest':
```

Instead of

```
if request.is_ajax():
```

as it's deprecated.